# Built in Mic not working in Skype

Tags: sound, microphone

I am using xubuntu on my E325 and I am having a hard time making my Mic work on skype.

I know that I have working mic, because I was able to record sounds via Sound Recorder, but Skype is for some reason not smart enough to use the same source..

I really tried to look on forums and play with the settings, but was not lucky enough to get it magically fixed.. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you already solved the problem, but... I am also having weird problems with my mic, it works normally most of the time, but once during the skype phone call, it just muted, the other person didn't hear me at all. I tried everything, pulse audio, alsamixer... but what finally helped was, even though it is weird, to unbalance the INPUT volume in pulse audio control - now the right (or left) mic is 100% and the other one is 0. And I disabled skype to set automatically the volume of the mic...the disbalancing is suggested in here [Microphone not working at all in Skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23036/microphone-not-working-at-all-in-skype?rq=1) 
hope this helps